# ASP.net C# Read LiteralControl <select> <Option> from code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

in My ASP code I create a Dropdown using

c# :

```
DivPlant.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<select id='" + SelectID + "' multiple='multiple'>"+Options+"</select>"));
```

ASPX:

```
 <div id="DivPlant" runat="server" multiple="multiple" style="float:left">
```

How do i get the selected values from code behind ?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to create the control in code? You cannot add it in the markup? In any case, you could add a `ListBox` with `SelectionMode="Multiple"` instead of inserting a `select` element in a `Literal` control. Retrieving the values in code-behind is easier when the control is present in the markup however.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my requirement is to have Drop-down lists with multiple selection capability.

Comment: According to my tests (on Windows, in IE, FF, and Chrome), both the select element with `multiple` and the ListBox are displayed the same (as listboxes). I don't know if you can really have a Drop-down list with multiple selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the selected value using Request.Form[]

In you aspx page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div id="DivPlant" runat="server" style="float:left">
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblSelection"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclick="btnSubmit_Click"/>    
</div>
</form>
```

In you code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SelectID = "ddlTest";
        string Options = "<option value='volvo'>Volvo</option>"; 
        DivPlant.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<select name='ddlName' id='" + SelectID + "'>" + Options + "</select>"));

    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblSelection.Text = Request.Form["ddlName"];

    }
```